# How to pass authorization bearer toke n to another request in Jmeter?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter

I'm having a hard time in creating my test scripts in Jmeter. I am testing a mobile app and I cannot proceed because there is no cookies after I recorded the session. Is there a way that I can pass the bearer token to the next request and will let me have the authorization to continue with the load testing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0uNA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy71c.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should get the token after successful authentication process somewhere in the request body or [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

From there it can be extracted using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and stored into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

Then you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) as a child of the next request and configure it to send the appropriate [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header

[image]